# Error while installing PyQt6 using pip3 in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, emacs

I was trying to install [EAF](https://github.com/emacs-eaf/emacs-application-framework) web browser for emacs in my pc, but the installation was unsuccessful so I tried running dependency installations manually and found that PyQt6 was having trouble getting installed (as is proved from the image provided)
[image: Installation failure screenshot]

P.S: This is my first question so please excuse any mistakes made by me.
I have already tried upgrading pip.
I am using Ubuntu Jammy(22.04.2).

Comment: Please always include error messages as text, put into code formatting. Don't psot screenshots on this site, unless you actually need to show something visually (e.g. your plot does not look like it should etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just quitting this idea because it even after manual installation, the plugin failed to get recognised by emacs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).